# weblogic jms connection oracle weblogic

Tags: java, oracle11g, weblogic11g

in my application we have configure a jms connection with weblogic 11g, and when the JAVA application read a message we see that the connection is open and closed after each message read.

its a probleme because the application is reading many many messages! does someone have this problem with weblogic before?

for this problem we decide to create a connection pool in our application by using GenericObjectPool from apache library.

we have win 30% of time after that. so we are proud of us.

but after a long time we have see that we have error with "closed connection"

```
ERREUR 02004 : Impossible de créer une session JMS
    at fr.edf.mpv2.commun.message.connection.AClientJMS.getQsession(AClientJMS.java:228)
    at fr.edf.mpv2.commun.message.connection.AClientJMS.connect(AClientJMS.java:124)
    at fr.edf.mpv2.commun.message.monitor.ReceiverThread.receive(ReceiverThread.java:159)
    at fr.edf.mpv2.commun.message.monitor.ReceiverThread.run(ReceiverThread.java:66)
Caused by: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.enableEventForMsgOrder(AQjmsSession.java:6550)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.<init>(AQjmsSession.java:486)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnection.createQueueSession(AQjmsConnection.java:657)
    at fr.edf.mpv2.commun.message.connection.AClientJMS.getQsession(AClientJMS.java:225)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareCall(PhysicalConnection.java:3645)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareCall(PhysicalConnection.java:3606)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.enableEventForMsgOrder(AQjmsSession.java:6541)
    ... 6 more
```

and i dont know why my connection is closed. weblogic can close connection sometime and the pool is not refresh so error commin? does i need to catch this error and try to create another connection before getqueueSession?

thanks a lot if someone can help me on this problem. I know its was not simple to understand but if someone can help :)

**EDIT #1**

here is the xml configuration of the connection in weblogic :

```
<jdbc-connection-pool-params>
<initial-capacity>10</initial-capacity>
<max-capacity>30</max-capacity>
<shrink-frequency-seconds>0</shrink-frequency-seconds>
<connection-creation-retry-frequency-seconds>600</connection-creation-retry-frequency-seconds>
<test-frequency-seconds>0</test-frequency-seconds>
<test-connections-on-reserve>true</test-connections-on-reserve>
<test-table-name>SQL SELECT 1 FROM T_PARAM</test-table-name>
<statement-cache-size>10</statement-cache-size>
<statement-cache-type>LRU</statement-cache-type>
<seconds-to-trust-an-idle-pool-connection>0</seconds-to-trust-an-idle-pool-connection>
<statement-timeout>30</statement-timeout>
<pinned-to-thread>true</pinned-to-thread>
```

the jndiname is configure in weblogic.xml

```
<resource-description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/jmsQueuingDatasource</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/ctrnat_fco_jms</jndi-name>
</resource-description>
```

here is the connection with spring:

```
  <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"   singleton="true">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/jmsQueuingDatasource"/>
  </bean>
```

i have a spring bean who get the datasource :

DataSourceConnectionFactory containt getConnection and releaseconnection methode :

```
public JmsQueueConnection getConnection() throws TechniqueException {
    LOGGER.debug("getConnection()");

    LOGGER.debug("Création d'une connexion à la queue de message.");
    JmsQueueConnection connection = new JmsQueueConnection(this.getDataSource());

    LOGGER.debug("Connexion réussie");
    return connection;

}

@Override
public void releaseConnection(JmsQueueConnection jmsQConn) throws TechniqueException {
    try {
        // on ferme simplement la connexion.
        jmsQConn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new TechniqueException(e);
    }
}
```

And my jms client is doing this to getConnection before getSession :

```
protected JmsQueueConnection getConnection() throws TechniqueException, JMSException {
    if (this.connection == null || this.connection.isClosed()) {
        this.connection = getConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    }
    return this.connection;
}
```

i hope it can help, if you want some information

Comment: its important to see your portion of client code where you establish the connection.

Comment: @SabirKhan hello, i add some code if it can help, ask me if you want to see something else ;)

Comment: i see that i can active test-connections-on-reserve by adding test frequency > 0 to tell weblogic to test the connection and second part is to replace isClosed by isValid to check really the connection? what about this solution? thanks